# Prove {$x \in \textbf{R}^n |c<|f(x)|<d$} is open for continuous $ f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f$ $\textbf{R}^n \rightarrow \textbf{R}^m$ be a continuous everywhere function and $c<d$.

Prove {$x \in \textbf{R}^n |    c<|f(x)|<d$} is an open set.

I tried to prove this by definition, i.e. a set is open iff every point in it has an open ball centered at the point. 
So take any point $x$ in the set, it follows that $c<|f(x)|<d$ , and by continuity, there exists $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $c<|f(x+\epsilon)|<d$ and $c<|f(x-\epsilon)|<d$. What is wrong with this proof?

Comment: You are not indicating exactly *how* you are using the definition of continuity to arrive at the conclusion.  E.g., if this is supposed to be based on a $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition, what $\varepsilon$ do you need?  A shorter proof if you have the background would be based on the following: $f$ continuous implies $|f|$ is continuous, and the inverse image of an open set under a continuous function is open.

Answer (score 1):

$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid c<|f(x)|<d\}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid f(x)\in(c,d)\}\cup\\
\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid f(x)\in(-d,-c)\}\\
=f^{-1}(c,d)\cup f^{-1}(-d.-c). $$
Thus this set is open.

Comment: You edited the question by $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. Thus you need to use the continuous function $|f|:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous, being composition of two continuous function.